# windws.location redirect to a URLencoded link

Tags: php, redirect

i am trying to redirect  to a url that is passed as a param from another page.

```
<?PHP $location   = urlencode($_GET['url']); ?>

    <script>
    window.location = ("<?PHP echo $location; ?>");
    </script
```

the problem is instead of redirecting to the external site, it thinks the encoded URL string is a file name relative to the current directory.

how can i make it redirect to the right place?

Comment: can you provide an example value for `$location`? Missing the protocol?

Comment: an axample string http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Faaa%3Dbbb

Answer (score 1):

you should add `http://` before your url

**Edit**

I noticed you mentioned you get a string like this: `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Faaa%3Dbbb`

So you can decode that string:

```
$location   = urldecode($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a php header direction method:

```
<?php
    header('Location: '.$_GET['url']);
?>
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
...for more details.

Comment: php header causes the same issue

Comment: I edited my answer. Since the variable is in a GET, it will already have been encoded. The encoded GET value can be passed directly to the header function.

Comment: Just tested it and its working fine. testscript.php?url=http://google.com
When I visit the php file it redirects me to google :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `urlencode()` and ensure the url is starting with `http://`

```
<?PHP $location = $_GET['url']; ?>
    <script>
    window.location = ("<?PHP echo $location; ?>");
    </script>
```

Or:

```
<?php 
$location = $_GET['url'];
header("Location: $location"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should verify the passed URL is in fact a URL and not someone trying to inject JS into your site.

```
if(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {
    header("Location: " . filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
}

//Alternatively using JS
if(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {
    echo('<script>
    window.location = ("' . filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) . '");
    </script>');
}
```